# space between images in static html disappears in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to understand why my white-space disappears when switching my code to javascript.

This is with static html [JSFiddle Basic](https://jsfiddle.net/John1234/51xbaox5/3/)

And here the "same" in javascript [JSFiddle JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/John1234/baentgv2/3/)

when I set `font-size:0px;` in css for the static html I get the same result as in javascript. I am just not sure why this is happening and would like to understand it. What is javascript doing differently to html/CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it's because javascript appends each section just after the closing tag of a previous section, leaving no space between previous section closing tag and next section opening tag.

HTML version:

```
<section>
    <!-- content -->
</section>
<section>
    <!-- content -->
</section>
```

JS version:

```
<section><!-- content --></section><section><!-- content --></section>
```

Comment: just tested it in static html without space and it works just as you say. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help @TheRealPir

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the basic html you have new lines separating the section elements:

```
<section class="pic"></section>
<section class="pic"></section>
```

In the approach with JavaScript they are glued together on one line:

```
<section class="pic"></section><section class="pic">
```

You can read this to update your knowledge for how to avoid the spacing between the inline-blocks:
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/